# Python dictionary ordering with equal keys

Tags: python, dictionary, floating-point, hashmap

I thought this must already have been answered, but I couldn't find anything on Google or here.

I'm aware that, in general, you cannot rely on the ordering of a Python dictionary. However, if you have two dictionaries with *identical* keys, can you rely on the values being in the same order as well?

I ask because I'm trying to compare two dictionaries of floating point numbers, so I cannot use `dict1==dict2`. My function looks something like this:

```
def _compare_dict(self, d1, d2):
    """
    Compares two dictionaries of floating point numbers
    for equality.
    """
    if d1.keys() != d2.keys():
        return False

    zipped = zip(d1.itervalues(), d2.itervalues())
    return len(filter(lambda x: abs(x[0] - x[1]) > sys.float_info.epsilon, zipped)) == 0
```

Is this a dangerous game to play? In one test, the order seemed to hold:

```
In [126]: d1={'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 10}
In [127]: d2={'b': 10, 'c': 7, 'a': 2}

In [128]: d1
Out[128]: {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 10}

In [129]: d2
Out[129]: {'a': 2, 'b': 10, 'c': 7}
```

But I don't know if this is something I can count on. Other solutions for comparing two dictionaries of floating point numbers are welcome too, of course.

Comment: The non-dangerous method is to sort the keys first: `if d1.keys().sort() == d2.keys().sort()`.  You'll also need to similarly sort on keys when constructing your zipped list.

Comment: dicts with just 5 or so keys can have different order of iteration just by inserting keys in a different order!

Comment: @happydave, what if the keys are complex numbers? or in Python3 you can't even sort a mixture of str and int

Comment: `sys.float_info.epsilon` isn't the right way to do this. Note that `10 + sys.float_info.epsilon == 10` returns `True`

Comment: @happydave, also `d1.keys().sort() == d2.keys().sort()` is always `True` since `.sort()` is in-place and returns `None`. What you have there is `None == None`.

Comment: @Avaris - oops.  Should have written `sorted(d1.iterkeys()) == sorted(d2.iterkeys())`.  Although in response to gnibbler's point about un-sortable keys, maybe `set(d1.iterkeys()) == set(d2.iterkeys())` is a better solution.

Comment: @happydave or `set(d1) == set(d2)`. This is ok because we already know the keys are hashable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def _compare_dict(self, d1, d2):
    """
    Compares two dictionaries of floating point numbers
    for equality.
    """
    if len(d1) != len(d2): # comparing `.keys()` is futile and slow
        return False
    try:
        return all(abs(d1[k] - d2[k]) < sys.float_info.epsilon for k in d1)
    except KeyError:
        return False
```

This **still won't work** for numbers smaller than `-2` or greater then `2` because you are thinking about epsilon wrongly

Instead you need to choose a way to compare floats that makes sense. You can choose to use a fixed epsilon, but that will only work up to a point. floats can be very very big.

It's usually better to use a relative comparison than absolute

Comment: maybe you can avoid checking keys if you return False with KeyError

Comment: @JBernardo, indeed you could, but there might be extra keys in d2, so be careful

Comment: Oh that's right. It would need to iterate on the biggest one. Or just checking the `len` as you did now :). +1 BTW

Comment: my idea was `... for k in max(d1, d2, key=len)` (but slower for similar dicts)

Comment: 'If two floats are within sys.float_info.epsilon they are equal.'  This isn't true (unless you're using IronPython, where they have the wrong definition of sys.float_info.epsilon).  For a simple example, consider `1.0` and `1.0 - 2**-53` (on a typical IEEE 754 machine); both numbers are exactly representable as floats and their difference is `2**-53`, which is half of `sys.float_info.epsilon` (2**-52 on most machines).

Comment: @MarkDickinson, Ah yes, you are correct. It's ok to use for `-2 < x < 2`

Answer (score 8):

Depending on how the dictionaries were built, you can't rely on that.

some example:

```
>>> a = dict.fromkeys(range(1000))
>>> b = dict.fromkeys(range(500,600))
>>> for i in range(500):
    del a[i]

>>> for i in range(600,1000):
    del a[i]

>>> all(i==j for i,j in zip(a,b))
False
>>> a == b
True
```

`a` is a much bigger hash table because it has allocated space for 1000 objects while `b` can only hold about 100 without growing a little. So the way the hashes are stored can change the iteration order

Comment: Indeed. [The docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) say `Keys and values are iterated over in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend something like this:

```
def _compare_dict(self, d1, d2):
    if set(d1.keys()) != set(d2.keys()):
        return False

    for key in d1:
        if abs(d1[key]-d2[key]) > sys.float_info.epsilon:
            return False

    return True
```

It's easy to read and it will return `False` as soon as it notices two values that are not within `sys.float_info.epsilon` rather than comparing all the values.

Answer (score 1):

dictionaries are not ordered, they cannot be ordered unless you use a [frozen dict](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0416/)  which exist in python 3.3

Now to compare keys you could convert the keys into a set:

```
a = {'a': 0, 'b': 1}
b = set(a)
c = set(a.keys())  # just another way to be clearer

b == c
True
```

or you could create a list and order it to compare them, I like more the set approach.